# .toc File doesn't Write closing brackets

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I have a macro for writing SI units that take numbers as optional arguments, but when these macros are used for ToC entries, the `.toc` file does not write closing brackets for optional arguments, messing up said `.toc` file during re-compile. Is this a fixable problem?

MWE :

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xstring}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn % Used for many other macros, so keeping this would be very nice
\NewDocumentCommand \meter {o o} {
    \IfValueTF{#1} {
        \IfValueTF{#2} { \ensuremath{\SI{#2}{#1\meter}} }
        { \IfDecimal{#1} { \ensuremath{\SI{#1}{\meter}} } { \si{#1\meter} } }
    } { \si{\meter} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[\meter[0.7]]{\meter[0.8]}
\end{document}
```

`.toc` Entries :

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}\meter [0.7}{1}{section.1}%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
\section[\meter[0.7]]{\meter[0.8]}
```

to

```
\section[{\meter[0.7]}]{\meter[0.8]}
```

i.e., enclose the expression `\meter[0.7]` located in the optional argument of `\section` in a pair of curly braces. That way, LaTeX gets the help it needs to parse the arguments of `\section` correctly.